# Flutter real device rendering issue

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-getx

I am developing mobile application using flutter. I was doing it like for some years, so my environment is OK. But like a week ago I tried to build another one application and when I sent it's release version to my phone from my computer I saw login page that was like that:
[image: login page]

The code of the page:
[image]

The thing is when I run my app in release mode on emulator or when I run app on my mobile using USB in debug or even release mode everything is OK, but when I open release file through telegram this happens... What should I do with that?..

Comment: Maybe try removing the `width: Get.width * .8`. You don't need to set the width explicitly since you're just center-ing the content on the screen anyway.

Comment: doesn't work for me((

Comment: have you found any solution. It seems like it is working well when I run it in release mode through cable but when I build apk, it give this issue

Comment: Actually, I upgraded my Flutter version and just did as you said. Everything is ok now!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second delay before first frame paint resolves the issue.

But its wierd though.